# xpages how to call other database js library in resources

Tags: html, xpages

How to import other database (content.nsf) javascript libray into my current databases resources in xpages. The below code is not loading the common.js file. Correct me

`<xp:this.resources>
<xp:script src="resources\content.nsf\common.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>`

Comment: Can your browser access /resources/content.nsf/common.js? Does the browser network inspector report any errors?

Comment: When i see the view source, it is appending my current database first like --> Office\report.nsf\resources\content.nsf\common.js

Comment: Add a / in front. So: src="/resources\content.nsf\common.js"

Comment: Same problem. Both the dbs are on same server.

Comment: So as before: Can your browser access /resources/content.nsf/common.js? Does the browser network inspector report any errors?

Comment: The network collection agent failed to start

Comment: You have to fix your "The network collection agent failed to start" problem in IE/Edge or use another browser such as Chrome or Firefox and then get back once you can see whether your browser can access the \resources\content.nsf\common.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a / in fron my of src to make the path absolute instead of relative. So:

```
src="/resources\content.nsf\common.js"
```